# Simple infinite series question

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Quite an easy question, but I can't do it. I've even tried the tests I knew wouldn't work, (integral test, etc.) and I don't know what to do.

> Determine if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^n (n+1)}$ converges or diverges.

I suspect it converges but I am not sure. (Not homework, just doing practice questions)

Comment: Care to give me a hint if you see it? I know it is really easy... anything I tried to compare it with I would just get the limit equals $0$.

Comment: Oh god dammit, I was thinking of a limit. Nevermind.

Comment: $\log_e(4)-1$ if you really want to know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We compare with $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$, the sum of which converges. Since $2^n(n + 1) > 2^n$ for $n \geq 1$, we have $$\dfrac{1}{2^n(n + 1)} < \dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: Thank you... :-) (Now wait for someone to comment that this is a strange comment :-)).

Comment: (My comments condensed into an answer)

Comment: @Aryabhata: This is a strange comment :)

Comment: @t.b.: ....... :-)